# NSMutableArray accessing issue

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I've searched and have no answer. I've created an NSMutableArray and am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in one place of access.
Here. This is declaring in the .h file:

```
NSMutableArray *buttons;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *buttons;
```

And this is the synthesizing and implimenting:

```
@synthesize buttons;
...
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {
        buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
...
-(void)addButtonWithImage:(Image*)image {
    Image *button = image;
    [buttons addObject:button];
    [button release];
}
...
-(void)replaceButtonAt:(int)num with:(Image*)image {
    Image *button = image;
    [buttons replaceObjectAtIndex:num withObject:button];  <<===EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    [button release];
}
```

But when I use this:

```
-(void)renderButton:(int)num atPoint:(CGPoint)point center:(BOOL)center{
    Image *button = [buttons objectAtIndex:num];
    [button renderAtPoint:point centerOfImage:center];
}
```

It works

Answer (score 4):

since you never allocate, retain, copy, etc. `button` you should not be releasing it

just get rid of the `[button release]`s

The [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) is a useful read if you need more info on reference counting.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I thought since I had stored the object in the array that it would have a retain count of 2 and I had to bring it down one. Or am I only storing a pointer to the object?

Comment: You should never worry about what the retain count is. What you should do is make sure to release anything you own. Since you don't alloc, retain or copy it, you don't own it. `buttons` will retain it, but it will then be the responsibility of `buttons` to release it. (It is your responsibility to release `buttons`, however, as you `alloc` ed it)